# PHP API error - -Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to query a website using the php query, but getting error:

```
$ php main.php

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/tp/stop_finder?
outputFormat=rapidJSON&type_sf=any&name_sf=Wynyard+Station&
coordOutputFormat=EPSG%3A4326&TfNSWSF=true): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 in /home/cg/root/7504993/main.php on line 14.
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Tried - "Integrated Windows Authentication", under Tools > Security > Local Intranet zone > Sites > Advanced, the target web site is listed.

```php
<?php
 // User's search query
 $apiEndpoint = 'https://api.transport.nsw.gov.au/v1/tp/';
 $apiCall = 'stop_finder';
 // Build the request parameters
 $params = array(
     'outputFormat' => 'rapidJSON',
     'type_sf' => 'any',
     'name_sf' =>'Wynyard Station',
     'coordOutputFormat' => 'EPSG:4326',
     'TfNSWSF' => 'true'
   );
  $url = $apiEndpoint . $apiCall . '?' . http_build_query($params);
  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  $json = json_decode($response, true);
```

Comment: You may need to send some sort of authorization headers. The 401 response is coming from the remote server, not your own. Can you share any API docs?

Comment: Looking at the API doc, seem like you need an API token to make a request https://opendata.transport.nsw.gov.au/api-basics

Comment: I found this (https://opendata.transport.nsw.gov.au/node/601/exploreapi#!/default/tfnsw_stopfinder_request), which appears to require an API key or OAuth authorization to access this particular endpoint. Do you have the credentials to access this API?

Comment: Thanks. Created a API key. Can you please guide me on a authorization header is created in PHP. I'm new to PHP and API so don't know much,